# release assets to private github organization repository

Tags: github, jenkins, github-api

How do I create release assets from Jenkins box to my private github organization repository?
From `Jenkins`, I want to create the release asset in `github.mydomain.com`.
**Organization**: FooOrganization
**Repository**: BarRepository

I was able to tag the commit and push to github which created a tab and attached the source files as zip/tar. However I want the binary assets as a release artifact.

Is there a step-by-step guide for creating github releases? What kind of authentication would be required? and How to setup auth from Jenkins? etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it. 
As per [Github release](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#create-a-release) docs, make a POST call to

```
https://github.mydomain.com/api/v3/repos/FooOrganization/BarRepository/releases
```

with below payload

```
{ 
  "tag_name": "v1.0.1", 
  "target_commitish": "master",
  "name": "v1.0.1", 
  "body": "Description of the release", 
  "draft": false, 
  "prerelease": false 
}
```

Ensure you pass in OAuthToken header. "Authorization : token XXXXXXXX"